# How to download All the URLs one by one and keep in different folders

Tags: java, html, csv, selenium, download

I have one html file where I have kept all the URLs(Download link for CSV files).I want a tool/program that has to go through each url one by one and download the file, Then keep the file in the specified folder which will be written in the same html file itself.

html file is a table with 3 columns
File name,File location and download URL

Url will download the CSV file after opening a new window (`target=_blank`).Also after download it will close the child window automatically if there is no error.

I have tried the automation(Selenium using java)

But there are some challenges as follows.

1. It should wait until the download completes
2. Sometimes the url may show error,in that case it should close the child window and return to parent window

I have resolved the 1st case by keeping a watcher which will check whether the file is downloaded or not each second(by counting the number of csv files in the folder)

I can switch to child window and check whether there is any error but if there is no error my driver is got stuck over there.

How to resolve this

Code to check whether error is there in child window

```
   public boolean foundError(FirefoxDriver driver) {
    System.out.println(browser.getWindowHandle() + "Parent" + parentHandle);
    String child = "";
    int numberOfWindows = 0;
    //return true;
    if (driver.getWindowHandles().size() > 1) {
        for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            numberOfWindows++;

            if (!parentHandle.equals(winHandle)) {
                child = winHandle;
                System.out.println("Child" + winHandle);
            }

        }
    }
    if (numberOfWindows > 1) {
        System.out.println("tostring1" + driver.toString());
        if (!parentHandle.equals(child)) {
            driver.switchTo().window(child);
        }
        System.out.println("Switched to child");
        Set set = driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println("Number of windows=" + set.size());
        //  System.out.println("Number of windows="+set.size()+"driver url"+driver.getCurrentUrl());
        //  System.out.println("tostring2"+driver.toString());
        try {
            // WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);

            System.out.println("Body text" + driver.findElementByTagName("body").getText());/////////////////////////////Here driver will get stuck

            //System.out.println("text"+driver.findElementByClassName("body").toString());
            //  List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElementsByClassName("ErrorBody");elements.size()>0
            if (!driver.findElementByTagName("body").getText().equals("")) {
                driver.close();
                driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
                return true;

            }
            System.out.println("No error");
            driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            System.out.println("Switched to parent");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Catch block page time out:" + e);
            driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            return false;
            //  driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? post the code.

Comment: Yes..I have mentioned in the description..Using java selenium

Comment: If you have not understood the question or needs more clarification just let me know..where you are not understanding ,So that I can give the inputs on those areas

Comment: post some code please!

Comment: Driver will get stuck because child window is keeps on loading until download...So in between if we check for the error it will get stuck over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used different method
using Jsoup to parse the html file and downloading

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author nudanesh
 */
public class URLDownload {

    private Document doc;
    String url = "", folder, file;
    private final File sourceFile;
    int i = 1;
    int r = 1, c = 1;
    int anchorCol = 3;
    Library lib;

    URLDownload() {
        lib = new Library();
        sourceFile = new File("Download.html");
        try {

            doc = Jsoup.parse(sourceFile, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(URLDownload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements rows = doc.select("tr");
        System.out.println("Size=" + rows.size());
        for (Element row : rows) {


                Elements cols = row.getElementsByTag("td");
                c = 1;
                for (Element col : cols) {
                    System.out.println("Row"+r);
                    if (c == 1) {
                        file = col.text();//System.out.println("File in main"+file);
                    } else if (c == 2) {
                        folder = col.text();//System.out.println("Folder in main"+folder);
                    } else {
                        try {
                            url = col.getElementsByTag("a").attr("href");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.print("-");
                        }
                    }

                    c++;
                }
                if (!url.equals("")) {
                    lib.setLocation(file,folder);
                    lib.downloadFile(url);
                }
                url = "";

            i++;
            r++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        new URLDownload();
    }
}
```

and following is the Library class file

```
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author nudanesh
 */
public class Library  {

    boolean downloaded = false;
    Thread t;
    int waitTime = 0;
    String baseLoc = "";
    int size = 1024, ByteWritten = 0;
    URL url;
    URLConnection uCon = null;
    String folderLoc = "", file = "firstFile.csv";
    File loc;
    private OutputStream outStream;
    private InputStream is=null;
    private byte[] buf;
    private int ByteRead;
    private int FolderInUrl = 4;
    private boolean rootFolder = true;
    private File resultFile;
    private FileOutputStream fileResult;
    private XSSFWorkbook workbookResult;
    private XSSFSheet sheetResult;
    private int updateExcelRowNum = -1;
    private int updateExcelColNum = -1;
    String date;
    private int waitLimit = 900000;

    Library() {
        /*System.out.print(Calendar.getInstance().toString());
         Date d=new Date();
         String date=d.toString();
         System.out.println(date);*/

        //t = new Thread(this);
       // t.start();

        date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.print(date);
        baseLoc = date + "/";
        WriteDataToExcel();
        baseLoc += "Business Reports/";
        createRowExcel(updateExcelRowNum);
        updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Report Name");
        updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Path");
        updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Status");
        updateExcel();
    }

    public void setLocation(String a, String b) {
        file = a;
        file += ".csv";
        folderLoc = baseLoc + getFolderPath(b);

   // System.out.println("File Name: "+file);
        // System.out.println("Folder loc: "+folderLoc);
    }

    public String getFolderPath(String b) {
        String path = "";
        try {
            System.out.println("path" + b);
            path = b;
            // path = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(b, "UTF-8");
            String p[] = path.split("/");
            path = "";
            for (int i = FolderInUrl; i < p.length - 1; i++) {
                rootFolder = false;
                p[i] = removeSpacesAtEnd(p[i]);

                path = path + p[i] + "/";
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return path;
    }

    public void downloadFile(String urlString) {
        // System.out.println("Started");
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            loc = new File(folderLoc);
            if (!loc.exists()) {
                loc.mkdirs();
            }


            outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(folderLoc + file));
            uCon = url.openConnection();
        uCon.setReadTimeout(waitLimit);
                is = uCon.getInputStream();
               downloaded=true;
            buf = new byte[size];

            while ((ByteRead = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("while executing" + ByteRead);
                outStream.write(buf, 0, ByteRead);
                ByteWritten += ByteRead;
            }

            //System.out.println("Downloaded" + ByteWritten);
            resetCounters();
            createRowExcel(updateExcelRowNum);
            updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, file);
            updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, folderLoc);
            if (ByteWritten < 1000) {
                updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Downloaded ");
            } else {
                updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Downloaded ");
            }
            updateExcel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error catch" + e);
            resetCounters();
            createRowExcel(updateExcelRowNum);
            updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, file);
            updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, folderLoc);
            updateRowColExcel(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Rejected the Download after waiting " + (waitLimit / 60000) + " minutes");
            updateExcel();
            waitTime = 0;
        } finally {
            try {
                System.out.println("Error in streams");
                if(downloaded)
                is.close();
                outStream.close();
                downloaded= false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void moveToFolder(String reportName, String path) {

        try {
            File repo = new File(folderLoc + "/" + reportName + ".csv");
            path = folderLoc + "/" + path;
            File pathFolder = new File(path);
            if (!pathFolder.exists()) {
                pathFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            pathFolder = new File(path + reportName + ".csv");
            System.out.println("Path=" + pathFolder.getAbsolutePath() + "\nReport path=" + repo.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Source" + repo.getAbsolutePath());

            //System.out.println("Status" + repo.renameTo(new File(pathFolder.getAbsolutePath())));
            System.out.println("Status" + Files.move(repo.toPath(), new File(pathFolder.getAbsolutePath()).toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING));
//Files.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error while moving" + e);
        }

    }

    public String changeSpecialCharacters(String report) {

        report = report.replaceAll(":", "_");
        return report;
    }

    public String removeSpacesAtEnd(String inputPath) {

        for (int i = inputPath.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (inputPath.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Before string is" + inputPath);
                inputPath = inputPath.substring(0, i);
                System.out.println("AFter string is" + inputPath);
            }
        }

        return inputPath;
    }

    public void WriteDataToExcel() {

        try {
            // file = new FileInputStream(new File("config.xlsx"));

            //   File resultFolder = new File("Results");
            //   if (resultFolder.exists()) {
            //       deleteDirectory(resultFolder);
            //   }
            // resultFolder.mkdirs();
            if (!new File(baseLoc).exists()) {
                new File(baseLoc).mkdirs();
            }
            resultFile = new File(baseLoc + "Reports info " + date + ".xlsx");
            System.out.println("Path" + resultFile.getAbsolutePath());
            resultFile.createNewFile();
            // rFilePath = resultFile.getAbsolutePath();

            fileResult = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        //      System.out.println("file success");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;

        try {

            workbookResult = new XSSFWorkbook();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Opening the browser");
        //Get first sheet from the workbook

        sheetResult = workbookResult.createSheet();
        //sheetResult.set
        //Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet

        //Get iterator to all cells of current row
        //ar.add(folderLocation);
        //  ar.add(firefoxProfileLocation);
    }

    public void updateExcel() {
        try {
            //fileResult.close();

            fileResult = new FileOutputStream(resultFile);
            workbookResult.write(fileResult);
            fileResult.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public void createRowExcel(int num) {
        updateExcelRowNum++;
        num = updateExcelRowNum;
        sheetResult.createRow(num);

    }

    public void updateRowColExcel(int rnum, int cnum, String value) {
        updateExcelColNum++;
        cnum = updateExcelColNum;
        sheetResult.getRow(rnum).createCell(cnum);
        XSSFCell cell = sheetResult.getRow(rnum).getCell(cnum);
        cell.setCellValue(value);

    }

    public void updateColumn(int rnum, int cnum, String value) {
        XSSFCell cell = sheetResult.getRow(rnum).getCell(cnum);
        cell.setCellValue(value);

    }

    public void resetCounters() {
        updateExcelColNum = -1;

    }

 /*   @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (true) {
                waitTime += 1000;
System.out.println(waitTime);
                if (waitTime > waitLimit) {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                        outStream.close();
                    //downloaded=false;
                        // cancelDownload=true;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Library.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    }*/

}
```