# How to avoid generating more than one thread while Initializing the driver/synchronize to execute by only one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I am executing one java selenium project..

```
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadLoc.getAbsolutePath());
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.http.response.timeout", timeLimit);
    // firefoxProfile.setPreference("network.http.pipelining.read-timeout", 1);
    System.out.println("Total number of threads in before driver fn" + Thread.activeCount());
    FirefoxDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    System.out.println("Total number of threads in after driver fn" + Thread.activeCount());
```

After executing this it creates 4 threads
But I need to run the program using only one thread.Because in my program I need synchronization..It should go step by step..Due to these 4 threads it is not possible.

In the specified class I have one method which is preceded by @Test
So I tried to make the method synchronized,But it did not work...As it said something like resource is used by some other process while moving a file.

So I need to run the program using only one thread.
Please provide me a good solution..
Please let me know if you need more clarification

Adding full code

```
     public void waitUntilDownloadCompletes(FirefoxDriver driver) {
        waitTime = 0;
        clicked = true;
        System.out.println("Parent" + parentHandle);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("waiting-----active count:" + Thread.activeCount() + "and time=" + waitTime);;
            try {
                createRowExcel(path, reportName, "Downloading is in progress- " + (waitTime / 60000) + " minutes" + ((waitTime / 1000) % 60) + " seconds", errorMessage, false);
//          //      updateColumn(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, (waitTime / 1000) + "s (in progress)");

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println("wait time" + waitTime + "time limit" + this.timeLimit);
            if (waitTime > timeLimit) {

                try {
                    if (closeTheChildWindow(driver)) {
                        try {

                            System.out.println("HTML" + html);
                            createRowExcel(path, reportName, "Rejected Download after waiting " + (waitTime / 60000) + " minutes " + ((waitTime / 1000) % 60) + " seconds", errorMessage, true);
                            errorMessage = "";
                            //                     //   updateColumn(updateExcelRowNum, updateExcelColNum, "Rejected Downloading after waiting " + (timeLimit / 60000) + " minutes");
                            //                      //  resetCounters();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("Total CSV " + totalNumberOfCSV + "Time in seconds" + (waitTime / 1000));
            totalNumberOfCSV = -1;
            if (totalCSV() > totalNumberOfCSV) {
                System.out.println("Csv greater than existing");
                if (!isPartialFileExist()) {
                    System.out.println("Downloaded successfully" + totalCSV());
                    totalNumberOfCSV = totalCSV();

                    driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);

                    clicked = false;

                    timeCounter = 0;

                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Partial file exists" + totalCSV());
            }

            try {

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                // e.printStackTrace();
                driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
                System.out.println("Error" + e);
            }
            waitTime += 1000;
        }
        breakWhile = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will be asynchronous to selenium no matter what.

You will have to make selenium wait for the page to load and the data to be available, using the WebDriverWait class. In example, to wait till a button is loaded and visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='button1']")));
```

Comment: Please understand my question..am not asking for the wait,I know how to wait for a particular element..am handling with downloads..so I should wait until the download completes and then move to another folder..whatever it is doesnt matter...Please just let me know how can I execute my program with only one thread instead of 4 threads...I have tried synchronize method..and it didnt work for me

Comment: selenium just doesn't support that. if you need to download the file and know when the file is finished, you can use selenium and this FileDownloader class http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: I have added my waitUntilDownloadComplete function...I am able to download files and move the files to respective directory.Also I have tried with URL class,This is Analytics 11g reports download..So am not able to download using URL object.But for Analytics 10g it is working fine

Comment: For Analytics 10g reports download I have used the method as in the following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778094/how-to-download-all-the-urls-one-by-one-and-keep-in-different-folders/23782065#23782065     Please review this